# Find string and replace line in linux

Tags: linux, replace, sed, find

I'd like to do the following, but I can't seem to find an elegant way to do it.

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
..more values
stuff = 23   
volume = -15
autostart = 12
more values..
```

Now the "volume" value may change, depending on the circumstance.  I need a script that can find that line of text with "volume = xxx" then replace it with the line "volume = 0".  What is an elegant solution to this?  This line in the text is not guaranteed to be the first line, so I need a way to find it first.

Comment: by the time I wrote my answer and tested in a shell, three others were out. I'm getting rusty!

Comment: @zladuric We just didn't test them :-\

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
sed 's/^volume =.*/volume = 0/g' file.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I need to pipe this back into the file correct?

Comment: @jliu83 Don't pipe it to the file directly. You can pipe it to a new file, then you can replace the original file with the new one using `mv`.

Comment: Thanks, and why, might I ask, should I not pipe to the same file?  I'm guessing some sort of a race condition concerning reading and writing to the same file?

Comment: @jliu83 Something like that. Also note that `sed` has `-i` option for modifying files "in place", but it actually creates a temporary file, too. For safety, I'd start with the command I show, and if you're happy with the output, you can add the `-i` option.

Comment: Also, can you explain the `.*` usage?  I understand here it means anything that starts with volume, but why not just `*`, why is there a period (ie, why `.*` not `*`)?

Comment: `*` is a quantifier. It means "match the previous expression 0 or more times". In this case the previous expression will be `.`, which is any character. In `volume =*`, it'd mean "zero or more `=` signs". Feel the difference :) See a short reference on [`sed regex`](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html).

Answer (score 2):

With sed you can say:

```
sed '/^volume/s/.*/volume = 0/' infile
```

Comment: can you explain this?  usually the "s" option is used before delimiter for substitution.

Comment: The first `/regex/` decides which line the following commands are applied to, in this case any line starting with `volume`.

Answer (score 1):

Pipe the contents into this command:

```
sed -e 's/^volume\s*=\s*-\?[0-9]\+$/volume = 0/'
```

Answer (score 1):

`sed 's/^volume=\(.*\)$/volume=1/g' inputfile`

Answer (score 0):

@jliu83, do some reading on regular expressions.  It'll make the pattern matching in the sed commands more understandable.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Comment: this is not an answer to the question