# How can I find & replace text in HTML, htm, PHP and txt files on a Linux server?

Tags: linux, sed

I would like to know how to find and replace text in all HTML, htm, PHP and txt extension files on Linux server at hosting provider. I can do SSH.

**Text to be found**:`http://mydomain.example.com`

**Text to be replaced with**:`http://otherdomain.example.com/MyDomain`

Please give me exact command and it would be much helpful if it can prompt for confirmation before replacement.

Comment: Look at the `sed` command, or maybe `perl` or `awk`.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12663501/find-string-and-replace-line-in-linux  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8384809/replace-pattern-in-text-file for starters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux command line global search and replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/471183/linux-command-line-global-search-and-replace)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way using `sed` and a `for` loop. Use the `-i` flag with `mv` to prompt before overwrite:

```
for i in *.html *.htm *.php *.txt; do sed 's%\(http://www\.\)\(MyDomain\)\(\.com\)%\1OtherDomain\3/\2%g' "$i" > tmp && mv -i tmp "$i"; done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i 's/http:\/\/www.mydomain.com/http:\/\/www.otherdomain.com\/MyDomain/gi' *.txt *.html *.htm *.php
```